# Event ID 153 causing PC to freeze up while playing one game: Tarkov

Tags: ssd, freeze, event-log

Having issues playing one game with this SSD malfunctioning, I think.

Any time I played Tarkov in the past month I've had this event ID freeze my PC for about forty secs to a minute. It doesn't cause BSoD, just freezing then I can play. But it often happens, at least twice a match, which is once every fifteen(ish) minutes. Reset to device, `\Device\RaidPort0`, was issued and The IO operation at logical block address `0x25ec8500` for Disk 0 (PDO name: `\Device\00000048`) was retried.

I've tried `sfcscan` without results. Also `dism`. I've re-seated the SSD and it did not work for a little, at all, then I re-seated and it was fine. Crystal Disk says drives are perfect and the M.2 is around 53ºC during a benchmark.

What I don't get is it's literally just playing Tarkov. Nothing else causes it.

Specs:

- Motherboard GigaByte B450 AORUS ELITE
- GPU Asus GeForce RTX 2060
- CPU AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
- 32GB of RAM - 4 sticks - DDR4 3200
- System SSD M.2 Samsung 980 1TB; other SSD is Samsung 860 500GB (I've moved the game on and off and still have issues on both).

Comment: What do the SMART diagnostics say? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology Use https://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup/

Comment: Please use proper capitalization where needed and don't be lazy when writing down specs. You're the one asking for help so it's your job to make it easy on other users to understand your system and not have to google most of the details like "5600X".

Comment: sfcscan will only detect a problem with Windows. It will NOT detect a hardware problem. Are these SSDs configured in a RAID configuration?

Comment: they are not in raid they are in ahci

Comment: everything through cmd and powershell is saying the ssds are healthy and no corruptions/fails.

Comment: We need the actual SMART data, not some binary ok / not ok status. Add the info (screenshot) to the OP.